# Duplicate documents for Canadian Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have been asked to upload relevant documents for:

1) Proof of financial means of support. 
2) Proof of financial resource of supporter.

Under the information section of both of these, they show some same documents. Do I need to submit the same documents again in **2)** if I have already submitted them in **1)**?

Answer (score 1):

Item 1 means documents showing **your** financial situation.

Item 2 means documents showing the financial situation of the person supporting you.

Comment: What if I am a student and 1) doesn't apply on me?

Comment: 1 always applies to you. Everyone has a financial situation.

Comment: I am a first year undergraduate student. I do not have any tax returns, I do not own any personal bank A/C (even if I do, that doesn't matter because I don't earn anything yet), don't have any personal assets or business. What can I do in this case?

Comment: If you really have no financial documentation then say that. I will not help your case.